# How to strike through entry in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I am using a `ListView` with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to show my DB-Entries.
It is working fine so far:

```
public void LoadListView(){
    Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllFahrtenbuch();
    if (mCursor != null){     
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.fahrten_anzeigen_list_view, 
                mCursor,
                new String[] { "_id", mCursor.getColumnName(6), mCursor.getColumnName(1), mCursor.getColumnName(14), mCursor.getColumnName(15), mCursor.getColumnName(16), mCursor.getColumnName(17), mCursor.getColumnName(20)},
                new int[] { R.id.textView15, R.id.textView1, R.id.TextView3, R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6, R.id.textView9, R.id.textView10, R.id.textView13});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());              
        }
}
```

What I want to do is to strike through an entry if a special value is received in an entry.
If the value of `mCursor.getColumnName(6)` is **0**, I want to *strike through the whole entry* in the `ListView`.

Is that possible?
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean "to strike through the whole entry"?

Comment: If you're using unicode, you can use it to strikethrough. (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough#Computer_methods)).

Answer (score 4):

Here you go.

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a [`SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) on your adapter and see if it is time to bind the data for the 6th column. If you are at that column and it has the desired value then strike through the entry:

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

     public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
          if (view.getId() == R.id.textView6) {
              TextView tv = (TextView) view;
              // bind the text to this TextView(I assume that it's a TextView)
              tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnIndex))); 
              // check if it is the special value.
              // if it is strike through this entry, whatever that means
              return true;
          }
          return false;
     }

});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the html tag `<strike>`in your text

```
<strike>This is a line</strike>
```

<strike>This is a line</strike>

```
public void LoadListView(){
    Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllFahrtenbuch();
    if (mCursor != null){     
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        String data  = new String[] { "_id", mCursor.getColumnName(6), mCursor.getColumnName(1), mCursor.getColumnName(14), mCursor.getColumnName(15), mCursor.getColumnName(16), mCursor.getColumnName(17), mCursor.getColumnName(20);
        if (mCursor.getColumnName(6).equals("0") {
           data =  new String[] { "_id", "<strike>"+mCursor.getColumnName(6)+"</strike>", "<strike>"+mCursor.getColumnName(1)+"</strike>", "<strike>"+mCursor.getColumnName(14)+"</strike>", "<strike>"+mCursor.getColumnName(15)+"</strike>", "<strike>"+mCursor.getColumnName(16)+"</strike>", "<strike>"+mCursor.getColumnName(17)+"</strike>", "<strike>"+mCursor.getColumnName(20)+"</strike>";
        }
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.fahrten_anzeigen_list_view, 
            mCursor,
            data},
            new int[] { R.id.textView15, R.id.textView1, R.id.TextView3, R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6, R.id.textView9, R.id.textView10, R.id.textView13});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());              
    }
```

}

Comment: What I need is to strike through in runtime.
I display all entries of my DB in the adapter. When an entrie (e.g. "mCursor.getColumnName(6)" is "0", I want to strike through all values that are displayed for the entrie "R.id.textView15, R.id.textView1, R.id.TextView3, R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6, R.id.textView9, R.id.textView10, R.id.textView13".

Not sure if it is clear what I mean...hope so.

Comment: Ya so whatever text you have you can append `<strike>` in the beginning and `</strike>` in the last

Answer (score 0):

yes u can for that u need to make custome daapter for listview in which in **getView()** method after checking ur condition for strike through u can set first text to your textview and after that use for that textview like

```
 yourtextview.setPaintFlags(yourtextview.getPaintFlags()|Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in your `getView`:

```
    if (strikethroughState[position] == 1) {            // your if condition
        first.setPaintFlags(first.getPaintFlags()      // set strikethrough on TextView1
                | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        second.setPaintFlags(second.getPaintFlags()
                | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        third.setPaintFlags(third.getPaintFlags()
                | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        fourth.setPaintFlags(third.getPaintFlags()
                | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
```